# How to prove f(x) is an increasing function?

Tags: functions

How to prove $f(x)=\frac{x(20-x^2)}{(10-x^2)^2+20} $increases when $x\in [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$? This function has three zeros at $0, \pm 2\sqrt 5$. I tried to find f’(x) =0 for the critical points, it becomes solving 6 degree polynomial equation, which is not easier than the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative is $$f'(x) = \frac{x^6 - 40x^4 + 40x^2 + 2400}{(x^4 - 20x^2 + 120)^2}.$$  It is noteworthy that $f'(x)$ is also a function of $x^2$; i.e., there are no terms of odd degree.  So $f'(-x) = f'(x)$ for all $x$ (i.e., $f'$ is an even function), and we can consider the related function $$g(x) = f'(\sqrt{x}) = \frac{x^3 - 40x^2 + 40x + 2400}{(x^2 - 20x + 120)^2}$$ for $x \ge 0$.  Then the denominator of $g$, being a square, is never negative, and in fact cannot be zero, since the discriminant of the quadratic $x^2 - 20x + 120$ is $(-20)^2 - 4(120) = -80 < 0$.  So we can turn our attention to the numerator of $g$; namely, if we can show $h(x) = x^3 - 40x^2 + 40x + 2400 \ge 0$ for all $0 \le x \le \pi/2$, we are done.  Since $$h(-10) = -3000 < 0, \\ h(0) = 2400 > 0, \\ h(20) = -4800 < 0, \\ h(40) = 4000 > 0,$$ we can see there are three real roots, say $$r_1 < 0, \\ 0 < r_2 < 20, \\ 20 < r_3 < 40.$$  There can be no other changes of sign in the value of $h$.  But since $h(3) = 2187 > 0$ and $(\pi/2)^2 < 3$, it follows that on the interval $x \in [0, \pi/2]$, $h(x^2) > 0$, therefore $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$ in $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$.